# C++ - my loop keeps on adding up to 0

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

so far here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int sum = 0;


for(num2 = num1; num1 <= num2; num1 +=2) sum += num1;
    num1 = num1 / 2 == 0? num1 : num1 + 1;
    num2 = num2 / 2 == 0? num2 : num2 - 1;

cout << "Enter the First Number:" << endl;
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter the Second Number:" << endl;
cin >> num2;
cout << "Total Sum: " << sum << endl;
  } //end for
```

but the sum keeps on adding up to 0 :/

here's the problem.

Create a program that displays the sum of the even numbers between and including two numbers entered by the user.  In other words, if the user enters an even number, that number should be included in the sum.  For example, if the user enters the integers 2 and 7, the sum is 12 (2 + 4 + 6).  If the user enters the integers 2 and 8, the sum is 20 (2 + 4 + 6 + 8 ).  Display an error message if the first integer entered by the user is greater than the second integer.

Comment: You can't expect the value the user enters after the loop to matter in the loop.

Comment: If this is the whole program, it's not surprising. You calculate the `sum`, which adds to 0 and **afterwards** read in some numbers.

Comment: I just tried it. still the same thing..

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the sum *after* getting the input!

But your whole calculation and loop usage is wrong. Here it's fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter the First Number:" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the Second Number:" << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    if (num1 % 2 == 1) num1 += 1;
    if (num2 % 2 == 1) num2 -= 1;

    while (num1 <= num2) {
        sum += num1;
        num1 += 2;
    }

  cout << "Total Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Note the following:

1. `%` returns modulus - `num1 % 2 ==1` implies that `num1` is odd. I took out your ternary `?:` operators not because they're bad, but just because `if` is easier to read and in this case you're not doing anything if `num1` is even.
2. You were setting `num2` at the start of your for loop. A `while` loop makes more sense in this situation, or a `for` loop without initialization `for (;num1<=num2; num1+=2) {`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is executed sequentially and the for loop initialization will make you lose the boundaries of the loop consider this code instead.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter the First Number:" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the Second Number:" << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    if (num1 > num2) // swap the numbers and do not print error message
    {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    //make sure to start from even number
    num1 = num1 % 2 ? num1+1 : num1;

    for(; num1 <= num2; num1 +=2) 
        sum += num1;    
    cout << "Total Sum: " << sum << endl;
  } //en
```

Answer (score 1):

While the homework (I assume) should be solved by you, here are a few hints to help you out:

1) Your for loop needs curly brackets around the code that is supposed to loop:

```
for(num2 = num1; num1 <= num2; num1 +=2)
{
    sum += num1;
    num1 = num1 / 2 == 0? num1 : num1 + 1;
    num2 = num2 / 2 == 0? num2 : num2 - 1;
}
```

2) Your loop is above your `cout` and `cin` statements, so it runs before the user ever enters any numbers. You need to move the loop to after (below) the numbers have been given to the program by the user.

3)
The logic of the loop is probably not what you want. Once curly brackets are added, this is what it is doing (in "pseudo-code"):

```
Let num2 equal num1 // Both are set to zero so this doesn't do anything
While num1 is less than or equal to num2:
{
    Add the current value of num1 to sum.
    if num1 /2 (ignoring remainder) is 0, then set num1 equal to itself. Otherwise, add 1 to it.
    // num1 already equals itself, so this doesn't do anything when num1 / 2 is zero.
    // 
    if num2 /2 (ignoring remainder) is 0, then set num1 equal to itself. Otherwise, subtract 1 from it.
    Add 2 to num1.
}
```

Unless the assignment says otherwise, it's probably best not to use the ternary (? and :) syntax because it's pretty confusing when you're just starting to program (at least, I thought so).

C++ is a challenging language to learn, but hang in there!

Answer (score 0):

1.)Get numbers
2.)Determine max and min
3.)Sum evens between

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
   int num1 = 0;
   int num2 = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   int temp = 0;
   int i;

   //Get your input values
   cout << "Enter the First Number:" << endl;
   cin >> num1;
   cout << "Enter the Second Number:" << endl;
   cin >> num2;
   cout << endl;    

   //just to reorganize and make num1 the smallest of the two
   if ( num2 << num1 )
   {
       temp = num1;
       num1 = num2;
       num2 = temp;
   }    

   //loop through and add even values
   for(i = num1; i < num2; i++)
   {
       if(i%2 == 0)
       {
           sum = sum + i;
       }
   }

   cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: To spice it up you could put the code in a loop so that it will repeatedly take values after running until the user says to stop.  But I'll let you figure that out on your own. Good luck.